# Using Dataset should I paginate in Server or in the dataset query

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I am using strongly typed dataset, for a website that I am creating

Should I modify my dataset query to bring 10 results every time or should I go with Linq and paginate through the data I already got from the list

For example, I can use

```
List<T> newsList = news.GetList().Take(x).Skip(x);
```

or I can go with

```
Select * from News Order By NewsId Desc Offset 0 Rows Fetch Next 1 Rows Only;
```

Comment: Better yet: we are in 2018, almost 2019, there are almost no good reasons at all to use DataTable/DataSet, let alone in new developments. You should be looking at using an ORM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My adivse is to **always** do Pagination and Filtering in the database query. Moving that to the UI only get's you excess load on the SQL server, Network, Memory. And at worst, race conditions/trigger update race condition detection.

This is even more true in WebDevelopment. The [page lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) dictates that the page is to be built, a postback processed, send to the user - and then instantly dropped out of memory. You would have to go out of your way to persist the data and that in itself can cause a host of issues. ASP.NET is even more vulnerable to OOM exceptions then normal .NET applications and database queries and Linq are right up there for culpripts: https://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/troubleshooting-system-outofmemoryexceptions-in-asp-net

Comment: While this answer has its good points, it's only in the first paragraph. The article is from 2009. There are almost no 32-bit OS now, and web applications have used tens of GB for many, many years. Also, that article does not mention LINQ a single time, so not sure what that point would be about.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Right, it mentioend RegEx, not Linq. It has been a while since I read it, so something might have gotten crossed in memory. As for the memory limits: You will jsut run into OOM's later, when it is harder to fix the design. And we are talking about DB table dumps. Some retrieval approaches temproarily double the amount of ram needed. And DB tables can still be GiB's worth of data easily.